# SQL Triggers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is as follows:

User name = Admin

Whenever I perform an insert/update/delete operation on a table "a". I need to have a trigger that would insert the username in table "b"

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create or replace trigger audit_a_trg 
    before insert or update or delete on A
    for each row
begin
    insert into b values (user);
end;
/
```

Oracle's online documentation is pretty good.  You can read the SQL reference [here.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm)

**edit**

`user` is a function which returns the name of the account which issues the DML.  [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions207.htm#i79833)

Comment: but how will the trigger know the value of the user?